# Get value of matched range key from json string

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have stored json format data in db, problem is it doesn't have quotes around it's values or properties.

```
"{1000:{AB DATA: NR, FC MATADATA: CR},
4000:{NK HX: I, NK FY: I},
8000:{XL LONG: I, NY CITY: I}}"
```

The object is likve below it's an array of object.

```
[{
        "current_milage": 0,
        "MasterVehicle": {
            "recommended_services": 
             "{1000:{AB DATA: NR, FC MATADATA: CR},
               4000:{NK HX: I, NK FY: I},
               8000:{XL LONG: I, NY CITY: I}}",
            "make": "Bajaj",
            "model": "Discover"
        }
    }
..........
],
```

I want to get the value of the matched range with `current_milage` from `recommended_services`

I want to find the value of the key from the json which is upper bound to `current_milage` value.
exp: `for current_milage=3500, 4000: {...props}, for current_milage=7800, 8000: {..props}`

End the end I want a structure like below :

```
data = [{
"Bajaj Discover": { 
        "FUEL LINE4000": "I",
        "FUEL LEVEL": "I",
        "FUEL STRAINER SCREEN": "C",
        "THROTTLE OPERATION": "I"
        } //{AB DATA: NR, FC MATADATA: CR
 },
...
}]
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
    const data = {}
    _.forEach(userVehicles, obj => {
       const current_milage = obj.current_milage
       const vehicle = obj.MasterVehicle.make + ' ' + obj.MasterVehicle.model
       const recommended_services = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj.MasterVehicle.recommended_services))
       const kms = _.keys(recommended_services)
       loop_1:
       for(let i = 0 ; i < kms.length ; i++)
       {
           if(current_milage < kms[i])
            {
                data[vehicle] = recommended_services[kms[i]]
                break loop_1
            }
       }
   })
```

It doesn't work. It give me

```
{
    "Bajaj Discover": "1",
    "TVS Star Sport": "1"
}
```

and `_.keys(recommended_services)` gives numbers starting from 0 like `0,1,2,3.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest trying to fix the invalid service json, I've created a function fixServiceJson to do this.

You can then perform the next service logic for the vehicles.

```js
function fixServiceJson(json) {
    return json.replace(/(['"])?(\w+\s?\w+)(['"])?:([^\/])/g, '"$2": $4').replace(/\:\s{2,}(\w+)/g, ': "$1"');
}

let userVehicles = [{
        "current_milage": 0,
        "MasterVehicle": {
            "recommended_services": 
             `{1000:{AB DATA: NR, FC MATADATA: CR},
               4000:{NK HX: I, NK FY: I},
               8000:{XL LONG: I, NY CITY: I}}`,
            "make": "Bajaj",
            "model": "Discover"
        }
    },
    {
        "current_milage": 15000,
        "MasterVehicle": {
            "recommended_services": 
             `{10000:{AB DATA: NR, FC MATADATA: CR},
               20000:{NK HX: I, NK FY: I},
               30000:{XL LONG: I, NY CITY: I}}`,
            "make": "Honda",
            "model": "Insight"
        }
    }
];

const data = userVehicles.reduce( (acc, vehicle) => {
       const vehicleKey = vehicle.MasterVehicle.make + ' ' + vehicle.MasterVehicle.model
       const recommended_services = JSON.parse(fixServiceJson(vehicle.MasterVehicle.recommended_services));
       acc[vehicleKey] = Object.entries(recommended_services).find(([km, service]) => vehicle.current_milage < km)[1];
       return acc;
}, {})
  
console.log("Result:",data);
```

And just to explain the line

```
acc[vehicleKey] = Object.entries(recommended_services).find(([km, service]) => vehicle.current_milage < km)[1];
```

The Object.entries(recommended_services) call gives us an array like this:

```
[
  [
    "1000",
    {
      "AB DATA": "NR",
      "FC MATADATA": "CR"
    }
  ],
  [
    "4000",
    {
      "NK HX": "I",
      "NK FY": "I"
    }
  ],
  [
    "8000",
    {
      "XL LONG": "I",
      "NY CITY": "I"
    }
  ]
]
```

We then call find on the array and destructure like so:

```
.find(([km, service]) => vehicle.current_milage < km)
```

This returns the next service, e.g.

```
[
    "1000",
    {
      "AB DATA": "NR",
      "FC MATADATA": "CR"
    }
],
```

And we access the second item in [1] to return the

```
{
    "AB DATA": "NR",
    "FC MATADATA": "CR"
}
```

service object.

Comment: It would be nice If you brief how this is working. Just explain `acc[vehicleKey] = ` line

Comment: It doesn't give me the same structure I needed.

Comment: I'll modify to give you the exact structure you wish, and I'll explain the line acc[vehicleKey], thank you!